# Why doesn't edittext change dp when the user starts typing in it?

Tags: android, addtextchangedlistener

I would have thought this is pretty simple but I've tried several things and it doesn't work. Basically, when activity starts I want my edit text to be invisible (I'm doing this by making size to 0dp, width and height).

Then, the idea is when user types on softkeyboard, the size changes, and user can see the editText and what is being typed.

Here's my code :

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.chris.sunil_gupta;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.CallLog;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

//create a ListView object called listview
        ListView listview;

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView_2);

        final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editText.requestFocus();

        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


                if (editText.length() > 0) {

                    //Your query to fetch Data
//            editText.getLayoutParams().width=32;
//            editText.getLayoutParams().height=50;
                    editText.setWidth(32);
                    editText.setHeight(50);
                }
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView android:id="@+id/ListView_2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </ListView>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:background="@null"
        android:inputType="phone">
    <!--android:visibility="invisible"-->
    </EditText>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry,change to this:

```
float density=getResource().getDisplayMetrics().density;
editText.getLayoutParams().width =(int)(32*density);
editText.getLayoutParams().height =(int)(50*density);
editText.requestLayout();
```

Comment: I think you mean getResources()? My                     editText.getLayoutParams().width =(int) 32*density;
editText.getLayoutParams().height =(int) 50*density; is coming up underlined in red, with the message in red when I hover : Incompatible types. Required: int, Found: float  Know how I could fix this?

Answer (score 1):

```
try it
 if (s.length() > 0) {

                    //Your query to fetch Data
//            editText.getLayoutParams().width=32;
//            editText.getLayoutParams().height=50;
                    editText.setWidth(32);
                    editText.setHeight(50);
                }
            }
instead of
 if (editText.length() > 0) {

                    //Your query to fetch Data
//            editText.getLayoutParams().width=32;
//            editText.getLayoutParams().height=50;
                    editText.setWidth(32);
                    editText.setHeight(50);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks Khizar, actually not in front of my machine right now but will give it a go when back. Although...I'm pretty sure I tried that already and it didn't work.

Comment: if it will not work then try this
if(s.toString().length>0){ body }

Comment: Thanks Khizar. Root of the problem though was that I was missing editText.requestLayout();

Comment: Welcome @ChristopheHarris

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
editText.getLayoutParams().width = 32;
editText.getLayoutParams().height = 50;
editText.requestLayout();
```

However, these values are in pixels. So, you may need to perform some conversion from dp to px before setting the values.

Comment: Thanks Ugurcan. I gave wngxao the correct answer as he gave me an answer that worked out the conversions. +1 though.

Answer (score 0):

try this. set minWidth and setHeight and set width and height to wrap_content

```
  <EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="0dp"
    android:minWidth="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:background="@null"
    android:inputType="phone">
```